# Frames(html) shows blank page of ruby on rails index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code in the index.html.erb file of RoR is

```
{
<html>
    <frameset rows="100px,*,70px">
        <frame name="test" src="test.html">
    </frameset>
</html>
}
```

When i ran my rails app, it shows blank page to me.
What i am doing wrong over here`enter code here`, can you please tell me what settings needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load `test.html` but if there is no test.html the page will be empty! Check if the sourcecode is loaded correct!

Also you should **NEVER EVER** use frames. Frames are absolutely outdated, there is no reason to use them! Its a disaster for search engines, also frames don't offer the capabilities css offers in combination with div`s and the list goes on and on and on,...

Comment: My file is in directory where index.html.erb is present. so , where should be my test.html file?

Comment: the way you incluide it the `test.html` file should be in the same directory like you index file!

Comment: My file is in directory where index.html.erb is present. so , where should be my test.html file? also which framework should i use instead of frames?

Comment: Thanks. for your suggestion regarding not to use frames. Now I am using css in combination with div's.

Comment: a framework isnt something thats about frames! A framework is a bunch of stuff that helps you to simplify your coding like rails does! But Rails isnt for the beginners. You should first learn html, css and ruby.